# Print only references not printed before, in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, subdividing

For a *Nature* style document, I'd like to print references after sections, but only if they have not been printed before.
I currently use this technique:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american,english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=nature,hyperref,autocite=superscript]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}

\begin{refsegment}
Main text\autocite{angenendt,bertram}.
\end{refsegment}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,segment=1]

Other info\autocite{bertram,gillies}.
\defbibfilter{not_printed_before}{ ( not segment=1 ) and segment=0 }
\printbibliography[heading=none,filter=not_printed_before]
\end{document}
```

This correctly does not print `bertram` again the second time around. However, this gets cumbersome if more segments are involved. Is there an automated way to check if a reference has been printed before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oooo. I can nearly do this, I think! Note that you need a `refsegment` for everything for my method of printing the max segment so far to work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=nature,autocite=superscript]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\pagestyle{empty}
\makeatletter
\def\blx@skipprinted{}% define a list to hold entries to be skipped
\def\addskipprinted#1{% macro to add an entry to our list
  \edef\X{%
    \noexpand\iffieldequalstr{entrykey}{#1}
      {\noexpand\toggletrue{blx@skipentry}}
      {}}%
  \expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\blx@skipprinted\expandafter{\X}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\addskipprinted{\thefield{entrykey}}}% add every item to the list
\defbibcheck{skipprinted}{% a check for our list
  \blx@skipprinted}
\AtBeginBibliography{%
  % run our check in the bibliography
  \blx@key@bibcheck{skipprinted}%
  % print bibliography for max segment so far
  \blx@key@segment{\the\csname blx@maxsegment@\the\c@refsection\endcsname}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{refsegment}
Main text\autocite{angenendt,bertram}.
\end{refsegment}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\begin{refsegment}
Other info\autocite{bertram,gillies}.
\end{refsegment}
\printbibliography[heading=none]
\begin{refsegment}
Other info\autocite{gillies,glashow}.
\end{refsegment}
\printbibliography[heading=none]
\end{document}
```

[image]